# ObjectListView - what properties control sorting?

Tags: objectlistview

I have a table that I do not want groups on but I do want to sort the rows by all columns. If I turn off Groupable then sorting quits working. Is there a way to fix this?

What properties control sorting and grouping and how do they work together/against each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off groups using ShowGroups (on the listview not the column)

```cs
olv.ShowGroups = false;
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that! Thanks!